# Regex Match Until Word Contained in Array

Tags: ruby, regex

Using Ruby 1.8.7

I need to grab everything up to a certain word - and I would like to match against words in an array. Example:

```
match_words = ['title','author','pages']
item = "Title: Jurassic Park\n"
item += "Author: Michael Crichton\n"

if item =~ /title: (.*)#{match any word in match_words array}/i
  #do something here
end
```

So, this would ideally return "Jurassic Park\n". I am currently matching on newlines but have found that the data I will be matching against might have newlines in strange places, like the middle of the sentence. So, I think matching to the next match_word would be a good idea.

Is this possible, or maybe can be done another way?

Comment: Off-topic, but it's Ruby with the regexes, not Rails.

Comment: I had thought that was probably the case. Sorry, will correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on for size

```
item.scan(/(title|author|pages):\s*?(.+)/i)
```

What this says is find all the results that start (case-insensitive) with either title, author or pages, are then followed by a colon and option white space and then characters. Capture the label and then the characters following the whitespace. The scan method will match as many times as it can.

Comment: Although the method @scott ripley used is closer to what I want to do (using a join to flatten the array into a string), this explains it well, and I think deserves the win. Thanks to all for good ideas!

Comment: After I answered with the same Regex, I realized that this will not work if the text has newline characters in "strange places". So please have a look at my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the match words and do the regex compare as you normally would.

```
match_words.each do |word|
    if item =~ /#{word}/  # Plus case sensitivity, start/end of item, etc.
        # etc.
    end
end
```

But if you know that the things you care about are at the beginning of the lines, then split the input string on `\n` and just use `start_with` instead of bothering with the regex--that partially depends on what the real data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `|` separated list of keywords from `match_words`. 
Then, use `string.scan` to split the string apart, giving you an array of arrays with your results.  [See the end of this tutorial for a reference.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html)

Here's my best shot:

```
keywords = match_words.join('|')
results = item.scan(/(#{keywords}):\s*(.+?)\s*(?= (#{keywords}):)/im)
```

Results: `[["Title", "Jurassic Park"], ["Author", "Michael Crichton"]]`

Don't forget to use the `/m` switch to indicate that you want `.` to match newlines.

To explain the pattern: we look for a keyword, then use a "look ahead" `(?= )` to find the next keyword without capturing it. We capture all characters in between using a "lazy" expression `.+?`, so that we don't capture other keywords.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, was very close - although the \m actually caused problems by making the match go beyond the newline (results were like ["title", "jurassic park\nauthor:"]. But this was essentially it :D

Comment: Hmm, now that I think about it, the `/m` is required to get results like `Jurassic\nPark`, but it fails because the expression is too greedy. I will update my answer with a solution for this.